# 1970s book about an imp bothering an old lady who lives in a closed-off section of a mansion

Tags: story-identification, books

In the late '70s, I was obsessed with a five-book box set that contained *The Secret of the Sachem’s Tree* by F.N. Monjo and *Timothy and the Two Witches* by Margaret Storey. I can’t remember the names of the other books in the set (all different authors).

The one book I’m particularly interested in knowing the title and author of is about an imp that is bothering an old lady that only lives in a closed-off small section of a mansion. Any information on the three other titles in this collection!?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Sounds like you're talking about books in the body of the question, so I replaced the [short-stories] tag with the [books] tag. Feel free to put the [short-stories] tag back if it's actually germane to this question.

Answer (score 14):

This looks like it may be the [*A Witch's Brew*](https://www.ebay.com/itm/203128980618) set, which consists of the following six books:

- *[The Thing at the Foot of the Bed](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/531411.The_Thing_at_the_Foot_of_the_Bed)* by Maria Leach
- *[The Secret of the Sachem's Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1766649.The_Secret_of_the_Sachem_s_Tree)* by E.N. Monjo
- *[Miss Clafooty and the Demon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2995340-miss-clafooty-and-the-demon)* by J. David Townsend ~ Illustrated by Edward Gorey
- *[The Strange Story of the Frog Who Became a Prince](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/878700.The_Strange_Story_Of_The_Frog_Who_Became_A_Prince?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=SfGvuQkPae&rank=1)* by Elinor Lander Horwitz
- *[Timothy and Two Witches](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1558562.Timothy_and_Two_Witches)* by Margaret Storey
- *[The Witch's Egg](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7200899-the-witch-s-egg?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=xtUYsLO0v0&rank=2)* by Madeleine Edmondson

Found with a search for `timothy "two witches" "sachem"`

Based on your description of an imp bothering an old lady, I suspect you're looking for [*Miss Clafooty and the Demon*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2995340-miss-clafooty-and-the-demon) by J. David Townsend.

[image: Front cover of Miss Clafooty and the Demon]

> Violet Clafooty was a miser! She lived in undisturbed serenity in the kitchen of a house so large no one knew how many rooms there were, and hoarded a stockingful of coins. She refused to spend a single coin, even for clothing. Miss Clafooty would walk down the street in her old-fashioned, patched, and pinned hand-me-downs and floppy picture hat. If people stared, boys hooted, and dogs snapped, she hardly noticed.
> Then visitors threatened Miss Clafooty's way of life; and the final visitor - the demon - was the most threatening of all.
>
> Black and white illustrations by Edward Gorey successfully capture the spirit of this amusing tale about a miser who outwits all of her guests but one! A story boys and girls are sure to enjoy.

Comment: Amazing thanks. I knew the illustrator was Edward Gorey but because I couldn’t find the book in his works, figured it was a different author. I am so excited for this answer thank you so much this has been plaguing me for over three decades!!

Comment: As per the [tour], you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.